# Выполнение php скрипта "в фоне" во время нахождения пользователя на сайте

Tags: javascript, php

Всем привет, стоит задача сделать так,чтобы пока пользователь находится на сайте в фоне выполнялся php скрипт, который никак не должен мешать взаимодействовать пользователю с сайтом(скрипт будет ждать некоторое время а потом делать 2 запроса к бд), при этом если пользователь выйдет с сайта, выполнение должно прекратиться, а если перейдёт на другую страницу, то скрипт не должен начать выполняться снова.

Comment: вот и повесьте на нужной странице по таймеру отправку аякс запроса к серверу. работа пхп скрипта заканчивается как только контент HTML страницы отправился к пользователю, нет там фонов никаких.

Comment: Мне бы не хотелось,чтобы пользователь знал о существовании этого скрипта

Comment: Вам по любому нужно как-то детектить - находится он на странице, или нет. Если у вас есть идеи лучше чем отправка ajax, то мы вас слушаем. Либо делайте по сокетам, поддерживать подключение...

Answer (score 0):

Это можно организовать при помощи поллинга со стороны клиента. Где-нибудь на странице вставляете вот такой код:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $.post('update.php', {});
    }, 2000); // будем дёргать сервер каждые 2 секунды
});
```

И на сервере создаём файл `update.php`, которые будет писать что-то там в базу.

Comment: Этот вариант подошел бы,если бы не проблема с безопастностью. Пользователи не должны знать,куда идет запрос.